# Variadic template partial specialisation "not more specialised" in g++ 7.1.1

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I have an equivalent to `std::integer_sequence` (we're not using C++14 yet). I also have two helper classes that remove or add a leading number.

```
// Sequence type      
template <typename Type, Type ... Values>                                    
struct Sequence                                                              
{                                                                            
    using value_type = Type;                                                 
};                                                                           

// Pop a value off of the start of a sequence                                
template <class Class>                                                       
struct SequencePop;                                                          

template <typename Type, Type Value, Type ... Values>                        
struct SequencePop<Sequence<Type, Value, Values ...>>                        
{                                                                                                              
    using type = Sequence<Type, Values ...>;                                 
};                                                                           

// Push a value on to the start of a sequence                                
template <class Class, typename Class::value_type Value>                     
struct SequencePush;                                                         

template <typename Type, Type Value, Type ... Values>                        
struct SequencePush<Sequence<Type, Values ...>, Value>                       
{                                                                            
    using type = Sequence<Type, Value, Values ...>;                          
};
```

`SequencePop` is considered valid in all compilers I have tried (g++ 6.4.1, g++ 7.1.1, clang++ 4.0.1). `SequencePush` doesn't compile with g++ 7.1.1. The error message is as follows.

```
test.cpp:24:8: error: partial specialization ‘struct SequencePush<Sequence<Type, Values ...>, Value>’ is not more specialized than [-fpermissive]
 struct SequencePush<Sequence<Type, Values ...>, Value>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:21:8: note: primary template ‘template<class Class, typename Class::value_type Value> struct SequencePush’
 struct SequencePush;
```

Is g++ 7.1.1 correct to reject this code, and if so, how does one tell that `SequencePush` is not "more specialised" than the primary template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
template <typename Type,
          Type ... Values,
          typename Sequence<Type, Values ...>::value_type Value>
struct SequencePush<Sequence<Type, Values ...>, Value>
{
    using type = Sequence<Type, Value, Values ...>;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0bcc137b8fb5df0)

as `Class::value_type` and `Type` from `Sequence<Type, Values ...>` are not *"related"*.

Comment: Although this works, I don't get why OP's original code would not compile.  At the very least the partial specialization should be more specialized because it includes a `Sequence` template template class.  What am I missing?

Comment: That's far better than my attempt :)

Comment: @Curious: Not sure of the correct wording, but `Type` is not more specialized than `Class::value_type` (even if it is constrained by `Sequence`).

Comment: @curious more specialized is a partial, not total, order

Comment: @Yakk can you elaborate on what you said?

Comment: I think I get it. This specialisation is detected as specialising Class::value_type, but the original wasn't because of the "using" generated a layer of indirection. Is that anywhere near what's going on?

Comment: @Curious: which is more specialized between `std::set<T>` and `std::vector<T>` or between `Foo<0, N>` and `Foo<N, 42>` ? -> Not all element are comparable. so [**partial** order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the general template `SequencePush` is parameterized by one template parameter (`Class`) but your specialization is parameterized by two (`Type` and `Value`). In the general template, `Type` is not a parameter as it is deduced from `Class`.

A working but not satisfactory solution would be:

```
template <class Class, typename Type, Type Value>                     
struct SequencePush;                                                         

template <typename Type, Type Value, Type ... Values>                        
struct SequencePush<Sequence<Type, Values ...>, Type, Value>                       
{                                                                            
    using type = Sequence<Type, Value, Values ...>;                          
};
```

<kbd>[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cff47bfdd4924861)</kbd>

Comment: Surely Jarod42's answer is still parametrised by both Type and Value?